# How do I join data from LibreOffice Base Table with a table from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, libreoffice

I need to join information on a remote MySQL table to a table in my LibreOffice Base table with a common field. Then, I need to run the report features of LO on this joined data, so a query or view would be helpful. The data in the MySQL DB is updated constantly.

How do I do this?

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Go on, try something...

Comment: It seems that LibreOffice/OpenOffice is lacking such a feature, see [buglist LibreOffice](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56234) and the linked [OpenOffice bug](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=42464). Maybe https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=54190 can help you.

Comment: @VMai Thanks for the link. However, I created two DBs in LO Base to test: DB1 and DB2, they each have one table and two fields in the table and one record. When I drag table from DB2 to DB1, all it wants to do is copy the table to DB1 instead of linking to it. Is there a way to keep the dynamic-ness of this? Could I use raw SQL processed by HSQL instead of LO Base to create a link? Does HSQL even support that?

Comment: @Dycius: I had the next paragraph in mind: "If you want to see SQL JOINs between 2 databases, there is another trick:
Create a form in a stand alone document. Conncect the form to a row set in DB1. Add a subform and connect that one to a row set in DB2 linked to the main form through some common field.
The subform shows records related to the selected main form record."

Comment: @VMail I was reading the guide to HSQLDB and you can do something like this:
[code] try {
     Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" );
 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.err.println("ERROR: failed to load HSQLDB JDBC driver.");
     e.printStackTrace();
     return;
 }

 Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb", "SA", "");[/code] Is there a way to put in raw sql statements to control the HSQLDB part of Base to connect to the MySQL server and form a view so it can be accessed by Base reports? The method you listed doesn't allow for report build. :(